# I would like to fly from the Aleutians to Japan

Tags: cessna-172, japan

I would like to know what is required to do this... what is the legal... what kind of fuel would I need to make the trip in say a 172XP Hawk.

Has anyone done this and what kinds of procedures should I be reading up on?

Where would be the best place to land once I reach Japan?

Comment: Hello Neeraj Maruka, welcome to aviation.stackexchange.com. Your question has many aspects: legal side, selection of airports, route planning, aircraft selection, fuel planning, contingency planning etc. That is too broad for one answer. Consider to break it up into multiple separate questions. Also, it seems to me that if you can't answer some of these questions yourself (e.g what kind of fuel do I need), you don't have the required experience for such a long over water flight, and you will be exposing yourself to a lot of risk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realize now that my question about fuel was misleading. I meant the amount of fuel. I have done flights over water (nothing this long). I am trying to imagine if it is even possible with a single engine to do it, or if it would require a fuel stopover in Russia.

Comment: To get started, you may want to research single engine piston ferry flights. I know they happen accros the Atlantic, I presume it's not much different over the Pacific. They sometimes use additional in-cabin fuel tanks.

Comment: Well... in your pilot training, there must have been some lessons on flight planning? Something like select route, select cruise altitude & speed, estimate fuel flow from POH, obtain wind forecast, calculate ground speed, divide route distance by ground speed to obtain flight time, multiply flight time by fuel flow to obtain trip fuel, add reserves etc. => that much fuel. Obviously for flights where aircraft weight and relative wind changes over the duration of the flight and position of the aircraft (i.e. any sensible flight), do above for short segments and over multiple iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SkyVector.com shows 1282nm from PASY, Eareckson Air Station near the end of the Aleutians, to RJCN, Nakashibetsu, Japan, the closest airport I could find in northeast Japan.
No wind, 10 gallon/hr, that's 128 gallons of gas needed. More than twice what a 172XP carries? (50, 60 gallons?) So pretty much the equivalent of 2 passengers for the fuel and tank. Don't forget the cold weather overwater survival suit, not fun to sit in bundled up for 10+ hours.

Now, if the Air Force agreed to let you land there, and agreed to let you have AVGAS brought in, and if the winds cooperated, you might be able to make it with a big ferry tank installed.

You might have better luck departing from Adak near, Mount Moffatt, PADK. 1612nm.
https://nfdc.faa.gov/nfdcApps/services/ajv5/airportDisplay.jsp?airportId=padk

The FAA site does not discuss fuel, you can check www.airnav.com for that.
Dutch Harbor, for example. Only Jet fuel is shown.
https://www.airnav.com/airport/PADU

If you had the Diesel 172, that could make the trip a little easier logistically
https://www.planeandpilotmag.com/article/turbodiesel-cessna-172-jt-a/#.XGBSDlVKjX4

> If there is an eye popping spec for the JT-A, it’s the max range, 963 miles, an improvement of 323 nautical miles over the 640-nm range of the Lycoming powered Skyhawk.

That would help a lot!